# Twilio chat, how set sum of chats to notification _bageCount

Tags: android, ios, react-native, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

---

Short description: I get push notification from *twilio chat*. But in my app I use 4 different chats (channels). So when I get field "*bage*" from notification it just show count of chats with new messages, but not amount of messages.

How can I get the sum of unread messages from all chats?

---

More info:

- I use **react-native 0.61.2** but I write native code too;
- During the work I have used this tutorial [TwilioChatReactNative](https://github.com/twilio/TwilioChatJsReactNative);
- For indicate unreaded messages I use [Message Consumption Horizon](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/consumption-horizon);
- The way of connection to chat (only react part) the close to this [Connect to chat](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/10/implement-chat-javascript-nodejs-react-apps.html);
- In theory I can get set bage himself, but for me this function don't work in background;

  > PushNotificationIOS.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber
- Also I have tried to use this library [react-native-notification](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications) but it didn't help too.
- I subscribe to pushNotification with this method

  > client.setPushRegistrationId('apn', token);
- When I use *twilio notify* and set "*bage*" by hand all work good, but notification from chat twilio do by himself.

---

Summary: I need one decision from this list (or something else, I open for offers):

- Say twilio send me sum of unread messages from all chats;
- Way how update "*bage*" from background;
- New way of subscribing to channels to get the sum of messages in "*bage*".

Thanks to everyone who will respond

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your questions and for using Twilio Programmable Chat!  I have opened this issue in the repo found at https://github.com/twilio/TwilioChatJsReactNative/issues/40 so that folks using the repo can see the answers there.  :-)